# Using two rectangles to cut from bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw

[image]

I need to cut an image out from a loaded bitmap using rect object and using the following method:

```
   canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
```

Where the CutFromBitMap is the rectangle object where I'm cutting from the loaded bitmap. The Dest is the rect where is the location on the screen where I paint the image. The problem is, as you can imagine, the bitmap isn't an infinite image and the CutFromBitMap rectangle object will run out of space and it's bottom will surpass the bottom of the loaded bitmap. When this happens I make a second rectangle and will start at the top of the loaded bitmap and connect both rectangles together to make it seem like an infinite image or like the image is starting again. This is what the code looks like when I do this:

```
                    //first draw the first rect
                int intersectionPoint = ((int)TopofFirstRect+treadmillBelt.getHeight()) - TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight();
                Rect CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofFirstRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight());
                Rect Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),intersectionPoint,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), treadmillBelt.getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);

                //draw the second rect
                CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofFirstRect,treadmillBelt.getWidth(),intersectionPoint);
                Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),0,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), intersectionPoint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
```

The canvas used is from a surfaceview. The intersectionPoint marks where the two rectangles should meet in the canvas (not in the bitmap, the bitmap is large and the rectangles should never touch while cycling through the bitmap).

[image]

So this isn't working and in fact the second rectangle never renders properly. Here's the whole method:

```
        private void drawBelt(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        boolean incrementFirstTop = false;
        boolean incrementSecondTop = false;
        float Speed = SMRRR.getSpeed();
        Speed = Speed * 4;

        //increment rectangle(s) position(s)
        if(FirstRectMoving)
            TopofFirstRect = TopofFirstRect + Speed;
        if(SecondRectMoving)
            TopofSecondRect = TopofSecondRect + Speed;

        //check if the rectangle has gone out of bounds of the bitmap
        if(((int)TopofFirstRect) >= TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight())
        {
            TopofFirstRect = 0;
            FirstRectMoving = false;
        }
        if(((int)TopofSecondRect) >= TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight())
        {
            TopofSecondRect = 0;
            SecondRectMoving = false;
        }

        //check if the rectangle bottom has just passed the bottom of the bitmap
        if(((int)TopofFirstRect)+treadmillBelt.getHeight() >= TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight())
        {
            incrementSecondTop = true; // move the top appropriately after drawing
            SecondRectMoving = true;
        }
        if(((int)TopofSecondRect)+treadmillBelt.getHeight() >= TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight())
        {
            incrementFirstTop = true; // move the top appropriately after drawing
            FirstRectMoving = true;
        }

        //canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
        //Log.e("Bitmap height", Integer.toString(TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight()));
        //Log.e("surface height", Integer.toString(treadmillBelt.getHeight()));
        if(FirstRectMoving && SecondRectMoving)
        {//need to render two rects
            //Log.e("two", "rectangles");
            if(TopofFirstRect>TopofSecondRect)
            {
                //first draw the first rect
                int intersectionPoint = ((int)TopofFirstRect+treadmillBelt.getHeight()) - TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight();
                Rect CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofFirstRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight());
                Rect Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),0,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), intersectionPoint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);

                //draw the second rect
                CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofFirstRect,treadmillBelt.getWidth(),intersectionPoint);
                Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),intersectionPoint,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), treadmillBelt.getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
            }
            else
            {
                //first draw the second rect
                int intersectionPoint = ((int)TopofSecondRect+treadmillBelt.getHeight()) - TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight();
                Rect CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofSecondRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),TreadmillBeltBM.getHeight());
                Rect Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),0,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),intersectionPoint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);

                //draw the first rect
                CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofSecondRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),intersectionPoint);
                Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),intersectionPoint,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), treadmillBelt.getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
            }
        }
        else if(FirstRectMoving && !SecondRectMoving)
        {//only render the first rectangle, second rectangle isn't necessary
            //Log.e("first", "rect");
            Rect CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofFirstRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),treadmillBelt.getHeight()+((int)TopofFirstRect));
            Rect Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),0,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), treadmillBelt.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
        }
        else
        {//only render the second rectangle
            Rect CutFromBitMap = new Rect(0,(int)TopofSecondRect,TreadmillBeltBM.getWidth(),treadmillBelt.getHeight()+((int)TopofSecondRect));
            Rect Dest = new Rect((int)((1.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)),0,(int)((5.0f/6.0f)*((float)WindowWidth)), treadmillBelt.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(TreadmillBeltBM,CutFromBitMap,Dest,null);
        }

        if(incrementFirstTop)
            TopofFirstRect = TopofFirstRect + Speed;

        if(incrementSecondTop)
            TopofSecondRect = TopofSecondRect + Speed;
    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? what the Rects are for actually?

Comment: the rects cut from the bitmap and gets pasted to part of a canvas that is in a surfaceview. So the reason i need two rects is because when one of the rect starts to get out of the view of the bitmap it needs a second rect to start from the top of the bitmap to have kind of like a continous flow of the image that gets pasted into the canvas

Comment: so why don't you just call `Canvas#drawBitmap()` twice?

Comment: or even better: use a `BitmapShader`